# iPhone Audio Buffer - Core Audio

Tags: ios, core-audio

I was wondering, is there a general buffer of audio data that the iPhone uses when using apps like Spotify, Pandora, last.fm or any other music streaming app? Do these apps send their data to this buffer to be processed and then played back on the device?

If so, would there be a way to access this buffer using Core Audio and then log the samples in Xcode?

For example, I stream a song on Spotify and my program reads this data and logs the samples.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way, on the same device, to access the audio buffers that Core Audio provides in the render callback function that an app would use to send audio data to the device's output.